# Place text over figures in sidesubfloat

Tags: floats, subfloats, floatrow

I'm using **\sidesubfloat** to put two pictures in a row.
I want to put a text over one of the pictures using **\put** command.
I used the following code:

```
\begin{figure}
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{FIGS/Vinesa1.pdf}\label{fig:vinesa.vectors}}~
  \sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{FIGS/Vinesa2.pdf}\label{fig:vinesa.bend}}
  \put(0,0){My TEXT}
\end{figure}
```

But it does not work well. It just puts the text on right corner of the figure with any x and y coordinates entered for \put(x,y) command.

There is no problem in figures without \sidesubfloat command.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try putting the \put inside the subfloat.  The floatrow manual says that some subfloats use separate pictuire environments.

Comment: Why not use the detail here: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/5764)

Answer (score 1):

For your question, do you still want to use \sidesubfloat and \put in latex?

If not, you could try the following code (otherwise, please ignore it):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.85\textwidth}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \captionof{figure}{left caption}
    \label{f:left label}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
    \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \captionof{figure}{right caption}
    \label{f:right label}
  \end{minipage}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```